# Parsing multiple csv files in a folder with timestamp

Tags: python, csv, time-series

I am trying to parse a timeseries data csv file in a folder which have timestamp in first column ( each filename is also timestamp) and delimiter is comma. In each file the only change is Server Totals and Client Totals fields ( i ve written the csv file contents below )

How can i combine all these files in one csv ? 
Note : i am limited to use different specific libraries, only time, os , pandas , csv , glob ( i ve tried to use all of these)

i tried this;

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = r'C:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\files\\' # use your path

all_files = glob.glob(path + "\*.csv")

li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)

print(frame)
```

Example single csv file ;

```
TimeStamp,Message/Event,Server Totals,Client Totals
1564981556,INVITE Requests,39967,37787
1564981556,100 Trying          ,39896,37758
1564981556,180 Ringing         ,1113,1113
1564981556,181 Forwarded       ,0,0
1564981556,182 Queued          ,1,1
1564981556,183 Progress        ,251,251
1564981556,1xx Provisional     ,0,0
1564981556,200 OK              ,913,913
1564981556,202 Accepted        ,0,0
1564981556,2xx Success         ,0,0
1564981556,30x Moved           ,0,0
1564981556,400 Bad Request     ,2,2
1564981556,401 Unauthorized    ,252,252
1564981556,403 Forbidden       ,320,324
1564981556,404 Not Found       ,487,487
1564981556,405 Not Allowed     ,0,0
1564981556,406 Not Acceptable  ,0,0
1564981556,407 Proxy Auth Req  ,998,998
1564981556,408 Request Timeout ,5220,5217
1564981556,415 Bad Media Type  ,0,0
1564981556,423 Too Brief       ,0,0
1564981556,480 Unavailable     ,49,49
1564981556,481 Does Not Exist  ,0,0
1564981556,482 Loop Detected   ,0,0
1564981556,483 Too Many Hops   ,6738,6738
1564981556,484 Address Incompl ,1039,1039
1564981556,485 Ambiguous       ,0,0
1564981556,486 Busy Here       ,159,174
1564981556,487 Terminated      ,2530,2530
1564981556,488 Not Acceptable  ,8199,8199
1564981556,489 Bad Event       ,0,0
1564981556,491 Req Pending     ,0,0

---


TimeStamp,Message/Event,Server Totals,Client Totals
1564982756,INVITE Requests,39967,37787
1564982756,Retransmissions,5,0
1564982756,100 Trying          ,39896,37758
1564982756,180 Ringing         ,1113,1113
1564982756,181 Forwarded       ,0,0
1564982756,182 Queued          ,1,1
1564982756,183 Progress        ,251,251
1564982756,1xx Provisional     ,0,0
1564982756,200 OK              ,913,913
1564982756,202 Accepted        ,0,0
1564982756,2xx Success         ,0,0
1564982756,30x Moved           ,0,0
1564982756,305 Use Proxy       ,0,0
1564982756,380 Alternative     ,0,0
1564982756,3xx Redirect        ,0,0
1564982756,400 Bad Request     ,2,2
1564982756,401 Unauthorized    ,252,252
1564982756,403 Forbidden       ,320,324
1564982756,404 Not Found       ,487,487
1564982756,405 Not Allowed     ,0,0
1564982756,406 Not Acceptable  ,0,0
1564982756,407 Proxy Auth Req  ,998,998
1564982756,408 Request Timeout ,5220,5217
1564982756,415 Bad Media Type  ,0,0
1564982756,420 Bad Extension   ,0,0
1564982756,421 Extension Reqd  ,0,0
1564982756,422 Too Short       ,0,0
1564982756,423 Too Brief       ,0,0
1564982756,480 Unavailable     ,49,49
1564982756,481 Does Not Exist  ,0,0
1564982756,482 Loop Detected   ,0,0
1564982756,483 Too Many Hops   ,6738,6738
1564982756,484 Address Incompl ,1039,1039
1564982756,485 Ambiguous       ,0,0
1564982756,486 Busy Here       ,159,174
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? The OP doesn't include a description of what is going wrong. Also, what version of Python are you using? If you are using Python 3, consider using [```pathlib```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) instead of ```glob```. By doing that, a lot of file manipulation functions are going to be abstracted and your code will be more portable among different operating systems.

Comment: @accdias i cannot print the data which i read. i am using python3 ; my latest code is below ;

Comment: Check my answer and pay attention to the forward slashes (it is cleaner IMHO and will work on Windows as well) on the filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not under Windows so I tried the code snippet below on Linux and Python 3 (adjusting `basepath`, of course) and it worked as expected:

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

basepath = Path('C:/Users/xxx/Documents/files')
li = []

for csvfile in basepath.glob('*.csv'):
    df = pd.read_csv(csvfile, index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(df)

df = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)

print(df)
```

Here is a proof of concept:

```
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 12 2019, 14:45:07) 
[GCC 9.1.1 20190605 (Red Hat 9.1.1-2)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> basepath = Path('csvdir')
>>> li = []
>>> for csvfile in basepath.glob('*.csv'):
...     df = pd.read_csv(csvfile, index_col=None, header=0)
...     li.append(df)
... 
>>> df = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
>>> print(df)
     TimeStamp         Message/Event  Server Totals  Client Totals
0   1564982756       INVITE Requests          39967          37787
1   1564982756       Retransmissions              5              0
2   1564982756  100 Trying                    39896          37758
3   1564982756  180 Ringing                    1113           1113
4   1564982756  181 Forwarded                     0              0
5   1564982756  182 Queued                        1              1
6   1564982756  183 Progress                    251            251
7   1564982756  1xx Provisional                   0              0
8   1564982756  200 OK                          913            913
9   1564982756  202 Accepted                      0              0
10  1564982756  2xx Success                       0              0
11  1564982756  30x Moved                         0              0
12  1564982756  305 Use Proxy                     0              0
13  1564982756  380 Alternative                   0              0
14  1564982756  3xx Redirect                      0              0
15  1564982756  400 Bad Request                   2              2
16  1564982756  401 Unauthorized                252            252
17  1564982756  403 Forbidden                   320            324
18  1564982756  404 Not Found                   487            487
19  1564982756  405 Not Allowed                   0              0
20  1564982756  406 Not Acceptable                0              0
21  1564982756  407 Proxy Auth Req              998            998
22  1564982756  408 Request Timeout            5220           5217
23  1564982756  415 Bad Media Type                0              0
24  1564982756  420 Bad Extension                 0              0
25  1564982756  421 Extension Reqd                0              0
26  1564982756  422 Too Short                     0              0
27  1564982756  423 Too Brief                     0              0
28  1564982756  480 Unavailable                  49             49
29  1564982756  481 Does Not Exist                0              0
..         ...                   ...            ...            ...
37  1564981556  180 Ringing                    1113           1113
38  1564981556  181 Forwarded                     0              0
39  1564981556  182 Queued                        1              1
40  1564981556  183 Progress                    251            251
41  1564981556  1xx Provisional                   0              0
42  1564981556  200 OK                          913            913
43  1564981556  202 Accepted                      0              0
44  1564981556  2xx Success                       0              0
45  1564981556  30x Moved                         0              0
46  1564981556  400 Bad Request                   2              2
47  1564981556  401 Unauthorized                252            252
48  1564981556  403 Forbidden                   320            324
49  1564981556  404 Not Found                   487            487
50  1564981556  405 Not Allowed                   0              0
51  1564981556  406 Not Acceptable                0              0
52  1564981556  407 Proxy Auth Req              998            998
53  1564981556  408 Request Timeout            5220           5217
54  1564981556  415 Bad Media Type                0              0
55  1564981556  423 Too Brief                     0              0
56  1564981556  480 Unavailable                  49             49
57  1564981556  481 Does Not Exist                0              0
58  1564981556  482 Loop Detected                 0              0
59  1564981556  483 Too Many Hops              6738           6738
60  1564981556  484 Address Incompl            1039           1039
61  1564981556  485 Ambiguous                     0              0
62  1564981556  486 Busy Here                   159            174
63  1564981556  487 Terminated                 2530           2530
64  1564981556  488 Not Acceptable             8199           8199
65  1564981556  489 Bad Event                     0              0
66  1564981556  491 Req Pending                   0              0

[67 rows x 4 columns]
>>>
```

If you want to work on files located in sub-folders as well, change `basepath.glob('*.csv')` to `basepath.glob('**/*.csv')`.

Let me know if that works for you as well.

Comment: yes you re right, it worked now with pathlib!! thanks..

how can i do these on multiple csv files? in each file there is a different TimeStamp column.. i want to append in only one csv file all the files in a directory..

Comment: The code above already works on all ```*.csv``` files located in ```basepath```.

Comment: If you want to work on files located in sub-folders as well, change ```basepath.glob('*.csv')``` to ```basepath.glob('**/*.csv')```.